# Adding university logo and company logo to my title page

Tags: logos

I would like to add my university logo and company logo at the bottom of my title page (like in the picture shown). For the rest of the pages, I would like to keep my Article format. How would you do it? My current code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{\Large\\
                Strategic order allocation at } \newline\textit{\Large\\Development of a }
            \vspace{2cm}
            \begin{Large}
                MSc. Thesis\\
                Maximo , 4950933\\
                \today \\
            \vspace{2 cm}\\
                \textbf{Delft University of Technology}\\
                Faculty of Technology, Policy and Management \\
                Complex Systems Engineering \& Management \\
                Section Transport \& Logistics
                \vspace{1 cm}\\
                \textbf{MSc. Committee}\\
                Prof.dr.ir.  \\
                Dr. M.Y.  \\
                Dr.ir. B.  \\
                Ir. A. 
            \end{Large}
        \end{center}
        \vspace{1cm}

    \end{titlepage}
```

[image: title page]

Comment: Welkom bij TeX.SE! Please post the code that you use to create your current title page, and a link to your class/style/template if you use any. That will make it easier to find a solution for your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Here is a simple solution, use `\vfill` to send the logos to the bottom of the title page, then use `\hspace{\fill}` between the two logos. The university logo will then be ‘pushed’ to the left margin, and the Heineken logo to the right margin.

If you prefer the logos further down, just add the command

```
\enlargethispage{<n>\baselineskip}
```

at the beginning of the page. Replace `<n>` with the number of lines you prefer.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\enlargethispage{5\baselineskip} %% <- moves the logos five lines down 
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{\Large\\
                Strategic order allocation at } \newline\textit{\Large\\Development of a }
            \vspace{2cm}
            \begin{Large}
                MSc. Thesis\\
                Maximo , 4950933\\
                \today \\
            \vspace{2 cm}
                \textbf{Delft University of Technology}\\
                Faculty of Technology, Policy and Management \\
                Complex Systems Engineering \& Management \\
                Section Transport \& Logistics
                \vspace{1 cm}\\
                \textbf{MSc. Committee}\\
                Prof.dr.ir.  \\
                Dr. M.Y.  \\
                Dr.ir. B.  \\
                Ir. A. 
            \end{Large}
        \end{center}
       % \vspace{1cm}

\vfill
\noindent

\includegraphics{TU-logo.png}\hspace{\fill}\includegraphics{Heineken-logo.png}

    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use command `\includegraphics[options]{image}` to add both images into your titlepage.

There are some errors in your preamble I corrected (see markings `<=======`) ...

I used `example-image-a` and `...-b` as placeholder for your images.

Please see that I used package `showframe` to visualize the resulting typing area and margins ... Delete that package for your final version!

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{caption} % <===============================================
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,labelfont=bf}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}% <================================================
\usepackage{showframe} % <========= to visualize typing area and margins

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{\Large\\
                Strategic order allocation at } \newline\textit{\Large\\Development of a }
            \vspace{2cm}
            \begin{Large}
                MSc. Thesis\\
                Maximo, 4950933\\
                \today \\
            \vspace{2 cm} % <================================ deleted \\
                \textbf{Delft University of Technology}\\
                Faculty of Technology, Policy and Management \\
                Complex Systems Engineering \& Management \\
                Section Transport \& Logistics
                \vspace{1 cm} % y============================ deleted \\
                \textbf{MSc. Committee}\\
                Prof.dr.ir.  \\
                Dr. M.Y.  \\
                Dr.ir. B.  \\
                Ir. A. 
            \end{Large}
        \end{center}
        %\vspace{1cm} % <===============================================
        \vfill % <======================================================
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b} % <=====
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

and its resulting pdf:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used tikz to solve this issue in my thesis. I added the tikz package and then an overlay at the end of your titlepage using a demo image. Since it uses the current page anchor, the rest of your document should be un-affected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{\Large\\
                Strategic order allocation at } \newline\textit{\Large\\Development of a }
            \vspace{2cm}
            \begin{Large}
                MSc. Thesis\\
                Maximo , 4950933\\
                \today \\
                \vspace{2cm}
                \textbf{Delft University of Technology}\\
                Faculty of Technology, Policy and Management \\
                Complex Systems Engineering \& Management \\
                Section Transport \& Logistics
                \vspace{1cm}
                \textbf{MSc. Committee}\\
                Prof.dr.ir.  \\
                Dr. M.Y.  \\
                Dr.ir. B.  \\
                Ir. A. 
            \end{Large}
        \end{center}
        \vspace{1cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[xshift=-1.35cm,yshift=1.35cm,anchor=south east] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[height=1.6275cm]{example-image-b}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output: [image]

Also, note, how I removed the \ after your \vspace{x cm} commands, as this results in an "There's no line here to end" type error.